# How can I hard-code questions and answers into a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I have an app where I intend to post questions to the User to help qualify a sales_opportunity. I don't want the user to be able to add their own questions, instead I plan to hard-code them into the app and use the answers they provide to drive a state-machine that will send them through the question tree in the correct fashion.

For example, I may ask "does the prospect have budget" which will have a Yes/No answer. If they answer "Yes", I'll send them to a question "How much budget?" and if they answer "No" then they'll be sent to a question "Is there a process to allocate budget?" etc. I need to save the answers they provide and give the opportunity to move back up the question tree (e.g. the user may initially indicate the prospect has no budget, but once the budget is available they need to change that answer and be sent along the path to determine how much budget is available).

I've defined all the questions I want to ask, the route they will head through depending on their answers, and I know what I want to do with the inputs, but I can't work out how to model this in Rails. I have around 50 questions and 8 different branches. Some of the answers require the User to link other models as part of their answer (e.g. I might ask "who signs off the budget" and the user has to select a Contact from the DB/add a new Contact).

Should I add a series of columns to an "Answer" Table, and add the questions as individual columns on the Question table, then use the gem State Machine to determine what is displayed to the user? Or would it be better for me to try and create an Object for each question?

This strikes me as something that should be relatively straightforward to solve, and I'm confusing myself/probably over complicating things. Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: I would store the next_question column on every question and simply redirect_to @question.next_question in the answers#create action.

Comment: You could have a helper method which gets the prev_question like `Question.where next_question: self` :)

Comment: How should I store the questions to begin with? Set up the model with them stored in columns?

Answer (score 2):

Modelling the data for this type of questionnaire is more complicated than one initially thinks. I did this once before and modelled it using a Question model, an Answer model, a SelectedAnswer model and a PossibleAnswer model. The latter 2 models cater for questions which have multiple answers which the user can select.

```
class Question
  QUESTION_TYPES = %w(TextField Checkbox Radio Textarea)

  has_many :answers
  has_many :possible_answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :possible_answers
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :field_type, presence: true, :inclusion => { :in => QUESTION_TYPES }
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :selected_answers, inverse_of: :answer, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :possible_answers, through: :selected_answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :selected_answers

  validates :question, presence: true
end

class PossibleAnswer
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answers, through: :selected_answers
  has_many :selected_answers

  validates :question, presence: true
  validates :text, presence: true
end

class SelectedAnswer
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :possible_answer

  validates :answer, :possible_answer, presence: true
end
```

A question also has a field_type attribute where you can set what type of question it is - textfield, checkbox, radio or textbox. This attribute will determine how you display the view for inputting answers as that will vary depending on if its a simple yes/no question or one which allows free text entry or one that allows the user to select multiple answers.

A question also has a position attribute which dictates the order in which they are displayed. In my example, I only had one branch. For multiple branches, you would have to use some logic to determine the next question to show depending on the answer.

There will be other ways of doing this but this worked for me. It allowed a fair bit of flexibility to use different types of questions and answers as we also used images for some of the possible answers.

Comment: This might be the best way for me to go. It certainly seems more complex than it should be at first look.

Answer (score 1):

- All questions are YES/NO
- A question when answered give a distinct rating on a **sale opportunity scale** (example 5 points for yes and 10 for no, or a simpler 1 for yes and 0 for no).
- A question when answered can lead to **two other questions** (if yes, if no)

So the models would be something like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_links
  has_many :next_question, through: :question_links
  has_many :previous_question, through: :question_links

class QuestionLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :previous_question, class_name: "Question"
  belongs_to :next_question, class_name: "Question"
  validate_presence_of :rating
```

You would define in a form (or hard coded) a Question with a link to a previous question (nested form) through a question_link (nested form). In this question link would sit the rating for one answer.

A question would have two next_questions (one with positive rating and one with a negative or lower rating). And at least one previous_question.

When a question has no `next_question`, that means the survey is done. You can sum all the ratings and get a score.

Comment: I just added the `validate_presence_of` to show where the rating should be stored

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the questions have multiple answers. Some are Yes/No, some are free text fields, some are other objects, and some are integers. I thought a State Machine would make the most sense for my use, as that way I can just use the position in the flow to determine a score.

Answer (score 1):

Lets describe your question from the point of data structure - since you have a linked question, it may be described as a graph. To be precise, considering "Yes"/"No" answers and defined routes over responses, this graph is a binary tree. Picture to get it more clear: [image] from the page http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~vhenrich/ss12/java/homework/hw7/decisionTrees.html

So, you need to keep tree structure in database with ActiveRecord. One interesting feature here that the relations between questions also have some information (the answer value - "Yes" or "No"). This knowledge should be persisted somewhere in database. I would recommend to introduce new model Answer to keep answer text and foreign keys to parent/children questions.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :parent_answer, class_name: 'Answer' # route to parental question
  has_one :parent, through: :parent_answer, class_name: 'Question'

  has_many :answers # we suppose to have maximum 2 answers per question
  has_many :children, through: :answers, class_name: 'Question'
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has attribute text: "Yes, No"
  enum text: [:yes, :no]

  belongs_to :parent_question, class_name: 'Question'
  belongs_to :child_question, class_name: 'Question'
end

# Let's create some questions
root = Question.create text: 'Is the picture clear?'
yes_child = Question.create text: 'Is there sound?'
no_child = Question.create text: 'Is the screen blank?'

# Let's build the tree
yes_answer = Answer.create text: :yes, parent_question: root, child_question: yes_child
no_answer = Answer.create text: :no, parent_question: root, child_question: no_child
```

Another question here is how to persist user's answers? First idea just create a relation `user has many answers through users_answers`

```
# model UserAnswer
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
end

# model User
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, throught: :users_answers
end
```

I would recommend to add a validation for `answers` that all records are in the same branch of questions/answers tree.

**Thoughts to improve:**

Hardcoded answers may be a pain point in future if you will have more answers. This might be solved with one model AnswerText and relation like `answer belongs_to answer_text`.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to try and get me on the right track. It looks as though it could grow into a very unmanageable mess quickly though (given I have 50 different questions and may want to write more in future). Unfortunately I've also got more than just yes/no answers that I need to persist (including some free text fields).

Comment: @Zoinks10 If you want to keep some free text from user, you can add just an additional field to model `UserAnswer` and that model is right place to persist it :) If you want to have more types of predefined answers, you can just extend model `Answer `